# Evernote Note Resource missing after updating it

Tags: ruby, api, resources, evernote

I'm creating notes on Evernote using the rubys-sdk `EvernoteOAuth::Client`. 
When creating a note, I create 2 resources that are attached to it:

1. a thumbnail, that is not part of the note content;
2. a logo, that is part of the note content.

After the creation, the note resources retrieved from the API looks like this:

`resources:[<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Resource guid:"some_guid", noteGuid:"some_guid", data:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:4285399715c412b4b67cbb5d34940974, size:1893612>, mime:"image/png", width:855, height:855, active:true, recognition:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:70294467148c7182dc454dbf66e97f19, size:11763>, attributes:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::ResourceAttributes >, updateSequenceNum:7565>, <Evernote::EDAM::Type::Resource guid:"some_guid", noteGuid:"some_guid", data:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:b830d7e35b9c6f43bd221be823f7e438, size:16173>, mime:"image/jpeg", width:302, height:75, active:true, recognition:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:38fc6770507b0d1c26625a86b7ea503a, size:525>, attributes:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::ResourceAttributes fileName:"logo.jpg">, updateSequenceNum:7564>]`

The thumbnail is shown correctly, but as soon as I open the note from an Evernote client, in this case the OSX client (the issue is the same from the iOS one), and the note get's synced, the first resource gets deleted and the logo becomes the thumbnail, with the side effect that the logo is not optimised to be a thumbnail.
Here the resource list after opening and auto-syncing the note:

`resources:[<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Resource guid:"some_guid", noteGuid:"some_guid", data:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:b830d7e35b9c6f43bd221be823f7e438, size:16173>, mime:"image/jpeg", width:302, height:75, active:true, recognition:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data bodyHash:38fc6770507b0d1c26625a86b7ea503a, size:525>, attributes:<Evernote::EDAM::Type::ResourceAttributes fileName:"logo.jpg">, updateSequenceNum:7567>]`

How can I avoid that resources gets deleted when the note is updated?
How can I specify that a resource shouldn't be used as a thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a resource is not a part of note content, it will get deleted. And unfortunately, I don't think you can specify how thumbnails are created. [This link](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/18482-request-choosing-a-thumbnail/) may or may not be of help...

Comment: The reference can be found here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php

_A resource is attached to a note by including it in the Note.resources list **and** referencing the resource from the note's ENML content using an <en-media> tag. Although it's technically possible to add a resource to Note.resources without including a corresponding <en-media> tag, there's no way for a user to view such a resource from an Evernote client app, and there's no guarantee that apps won't remove these "orphaned" resources._